# detecting asp.net redirecting users to login page

Tags: .net, asp.net, redirect, authentication

i have a directory in my website that is protected from anonymous users. my web.config looks like this

```
<location path="members">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow roles="members" />
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

if anonymous users try to access pages in the "/members" directory they will be redirected to the login page.

from the codebehind on the login page, **is there a way to tell the difference** between a user being redirected this way versus the user manually going to the login page? (either by typing in the url or clicking on a link to the login page)

i know the web is stateless so perhaps these two requests are indistinguishable

if it's not possible to distinguish between the two, is there a way to intercept what happens before .net decides to redirect the user because of an unauthorized access attempt?

note: i can't use the "ReturnUrl" in the querystring because i will decorate it the same way

Answer (score 1):

You can check "Referrer" [request header](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.36)

> The Referer[sic] request-header field allows the client to specify, for the server's benefit, the address (URI) of the resource from which the Request-URI was obtained (the "referrer", although the header field is misspelled.)

But browser can lie about referrer. Also look at [this article](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/security/tutorial-07-cs.aspx), it provides some examples about unauthorized access and it contains completely description how asp.net authorization works.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from checking the Referer, you could also check the query string for the "ReturnUrl" property. Which would indicate that Asp.Net had redirected the user. Again it's not 100% though.